# Custom events for dynamic inserted elements

Tags: jquery

I want to subscribe to a custom event, and use it with dynamically inserted elements

I've tried this

```
  $.fn.changeOrDelayedKey = function(fn, iKeyDelay, sKeyEvent) {
    var iTimeoutId,
        oEventData;

    // second signature used, update the variables
    if (!$.isFunction(fn)) {
        oEventData = arguments[0];
        fn = arguments[1];
        iKeyDelay = arguments[2];
        sKeyEvent = arguments[3];
    }

    if (!iKeyDelay || 0 > iKeyDelay) {
        iKeyDelay = 500;
    }

    if (!sKeyEvent || !this[sKeyEvent]) {
        sKeyEvent = 'keydown';
    }

    // non-delayed event callback, should clear any timeouts, then
    // call the original callback function
    function fnExecCallback() {
        clearTimeout(iTimeoutId);
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // delayed event callback, should call the non-delayed callback
    // after a short interval
    function fnDelayCallback() {
        var that = this,
            args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(iTimeoutId);
        iTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            fnExecCallback.apply(that, args);
        }, iKeyDelay);
    }

    if (oEventData) {
        this[sKeyEvent](oEventData, fnDelayCallback);
    }
    else {
        this[sKeyEvent](fnDelayCallback);
    }

    return this;
  };



  $('#new_shipment').on('changeOrDelayedKey', '.observe_price', (function() {
    cargoflux.resetCalculatedFields();
    if (cargoflux.validInput()) {
      console.log('Valid input, getting products..')
      cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
    }
  })
```

I know only the `.on()` activates on dynamically inserted elements, but I have no idea on how to use it with a custom event

any ideas?

Comment: Most likely you need to call `$(this).trigger('changeOrDelayedKey')` in your `$.fn.changeOrDelayedKey` plugin.

Comment: Is your `id="new_shipment "` is in new dynamically created html or initially loaded html? your on selector should select a initially loaded html.

Comment: `id="new_shipment` is just the page wrapper, `observe_price` is the dynamically appended element

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?